# CICD with TFS and release management

Tags: tfs, release-management

I am very new to TFS and Release management provided by Microsoft, I have experience of CICd using Jenkins and git as well, Now i have to implement CICD using Microsoft's release management on premises, please provide me guidance how can I buidl CICD and release management setup on premises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some links for you:

1. High level view on CI/CD: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1
2. MS Lab for CI with TFS: https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/tfs/build/
3. MS Lab for CD with TFS: https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/tfs/releasemanagement/
4. Detailed steps for CI: https://beeming.net/vsts-tfs/2017/4/setting-up-a-standard-continuous-integration-build-with-vststfs

Comment: Thanks Shamray, but I wanted to establish CICD infrastructure on premises, do not want to use any azure services, what I want is install and configure release management server and its component then want to integrate it with TFS, then CICD on remote machine

Comment: All links are applied  to local installation (only CD with TFS include 'Exercise 3: Releasing To Azure' that you may skip).

Comment: Also this links maybe helpful: [Deploy your Web Deploy package to IIS servers using WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm), [Deploy: Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy)

Comment: @HeenaPatel The links provided by Shamray is enough for you.  The release management feature is integrated into TFS, you can use it directly. See below articles for details : 1- [What is Release Management?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/what-is-release-management) , 2-[Release definitions in Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/), 3-[Create and deploy a release](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/actions/create-deploy-releases)

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you for your valuable suggestions